# Bitwise operator gave me a negative number

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I just learned. How Bitwise operators work but when i try to use it in the c code i doesnt work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 7;

    printf("%d\n", (int)~a);

    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is 8 but it comes -8.

`~0111`

=

`1000`

Comment: The type int does not contain 4 bits. All its bits are inversed including the sign bit.

Comment: Mask with 0x000f.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `int` is 32 bit on your machine then `7` is `0b00000000000000000000000000000111` and `~7` becomes `0b11111111111111111111111111111000` which is `-8`.

#### Background

For signed values the most significant bit is used to determine if the value is negative or not. When the MSB is set, the value is negative.

In addition to that `(char) 0b10000000` is -128 and `(char) 0b11111111` is -1.

So counting works as follows:

```
0b10000000 0b10000001 [...]  0b11111111 0b00000000  [...] 0b01111111
   -128       -127    [...]      -1          0      [...]     127
```

That is the reason why you will get -128 when you count 127+1 and try to store that in a `char`.